# Can I have Unity/eOS/OS X - like top panel that merges with maximized window's title bar in LXDE?

Tags: panel, lxde, lxpanel

Everything is in the title:
Can I set up a panel in LXDE so it merges with window's title bar when the window is maximized? Like it is in Unity, Elementary OS or OS X.